# Replacing using awk/sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a SQL query:

```
update SCOTT.GLOBAL set DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_STARTS=TO_DATE('03/31/2013 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_ENDS=TO_DATE('10/27/2011 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where zone='GMT';
```

I want to replace every occurance of `TO_DATE` with a random number/string and also want the correcponding `TO_DATE` and random number/string to be saved in a file.
For example:

```
update SCOTT.GLOBAL set DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_STARTS=abc, DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_ENDS=pqr where zone='GMT';
```

File:

```
TO_DATE('03/31/2013 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')~~~~abc
TO_DATE('10/27/2011 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')~~~~pqr
```

How can I achieve this with awk/sed/perl?

I have certainly tried something, though did not share with SO here. Apologies. Here is what I have tried:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/TO_DATE(.*?)\)/abc/g" my.out
```

This replaces the occurances of `TO_DATE` but I cannot figure how I can generate separate random numbers in same line for two different occurances of `TO_DATE`, and save them to the file along with the corresponding `TO_DATE` clause.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We'll help you find problems with your code, but "I need a dev to write a solution for me in one of there three languages" goes beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your needs you can try in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) something like bellow:

```
while read x; do
  while [[ $x =~ TO_DATE\([^\)]+\) ]]; do
    rand=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=3 count=1 2>/dev/null|base64)
    x=${x/$BASH_REMATCH/$rand}
  done
  echo $x
done<<XXX
update SCOTT.GLOBAL set DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_STARTS=TO_DATE('03/31/2013 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_ENDS=TO_DATE('10/27/2011 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') where zone='GMT';
XXX
```

Output

```
update SCOTT.GLOBAL set DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_STARTS=YsuW, DAY_LIGHT_SAVING_ENDS=5Vve where zone='GMT';
```

This read every lines from a file (which is replaced by a here-is-the-document here). If the line matches with the `TO_DATE\([^\)]+\)` pattern it creates a semi-random string from the matching proportion reading `/dev/urandom` and replaces the found string with this encrypted string. Because of `base64` the `bs` in `dd` always should be multiple of 3 to avoid the `=` character from the end. It only works if the `+` and `/` is acceptable in the random string.